# Unable to display the row data in angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dynamic JSON by using which I want to display the table the issue is any key with dot notation is not able display in the row below is my code

**.ts code :**

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['_id', 'subdomain', 'domain', 'part_id','info.mimetype','infodependent'];
  dataSource = [];
  public data = [
    {
      "_id": "c9d5ab1a",
      "subdomain": "wing",
      "domain": "aircraft",
      "part_id": "c9d5ab1a",
      "info.mimetype": "application/json",
      "infodependent": "parent"
    },
    {

      "_id": "c1859902",
      "subdomain": "tail",
       "domain": "aircraft",
       "part_id": "c1859902",
       "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
       "infodependent": "c9d5ab1a",
    },
    {
      "_id": "1b0b0a26",
      "subdomain": "fuel",
      "domain": "aircraft",
      "part_id": "1b0b0a26",
      "info.mimetype": "image/jpeg",
      "infodependent": "no_parent"
    }
  ]

  constructor(){
    console.log(this.data);
    this.displayedColumns;
    this.dataSource = this.data;
  }
```

**.html code**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">


        <ng-container matColumnDef="_id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element._id}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="subdomain">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>subdomain </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.subdomain}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="domain">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>domain </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.domain}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="part_id">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> part_id </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.part_id}} </td>
        </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="info.mimetype">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>info.mimetype </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.info.mimetype}} </td>
        </ng-container>


         <ng-container matColumnDef="infodependent">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>info.dependent </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.infodependent}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>


</table>
```

currently when i am using the above code my table is displayed like below 
[image: table code]

now i need two clarification
1. why with dot notation the values is not displaying ?
2. even though the other field is not having the dot notation why it is not displaying the filed?

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like you're probably getting an error similar to `property 'info' does not exist on object 'element'` or something. Like with plain js the using symbols or spaces like `.`  the property name needs to be surrounded in quotes and called using bracket notation. Try `{{element['info.mimetype']}}` instead

Comment: @MichaelSorensen it is working now  with {{element['info.mimetype']}}

Comment: Awesome! I'll add the comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code it looks like you're probably getting an error similar to `property 'info' does not exist on object 'element'` or something. Like with plain js the using symbols or spaces like . the property name needs to be surrounded in quotes and called using bracket notation. Try `{{element['info.mimetype']}}` instead